# How to execute something in terminal with URI Scheme? (vagrant:// ...)

Tags: linux, terminal, vagrant, uri

How can I run something through my own terminal that starts with a URI Scheme? For example, when running IntelliJ's Phpstorm with Vagrant, executing code tests from Phpstorm outputs something like:

`vagrant:///home/user/Projects/Homestead/usr/bin/php phpunit ...`

Now my question is how can I execute something through my terminal in the above sense. Not like ssh-ing to a vagrant machine and then doing stuff. I explicitly need the way to do this through my terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming vagrant has [set up the system appropriately](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118793/how-can-i-set-yate-to-be-my-default-tel-protocol-handler), use `xdg-open`.

```
xdg-open vagrant://....
```